# Accessing data from filtered group dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

With regards to the Gain/Loss chart on the dc.js homepage how would i access the gain or loss totals that you see when rolling over the chart.

something similar to this i suspect but i just can't get it to work:

y.innerHTML = String(stores.filter(function(d) { return d.gain != 0; }).length);

Answer (score 1):

Crossfilter uses "group" objects to aggregate the data, and this is what dc.js is displaying.

In this case, to fetch the data for the "Days by Gain/Loss" pie chart, you can do

```
gainOrLossChart.group().all()
```

which returns an array of `{key,value}` objects:

```
[{key: "Gain", value: 3628}, {key: "Loss", value: 3096}]
```

See [the Crossfilter API Reference](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) for more information.